# How to use setscheduler (what Includes are needed)?

Tags: linux-kernel

I am trying to use the setscheduler (in the linux (2.4) kernel) to change some parameters,
I tried to compile my file and I got an error:undefined reference.
what are the includes needed to use setscheduler ?
thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're in luck, the `#include` is right at the top of the man page :)

> ```
> NAME
>        sched_setscheduler, sched_getscheduler - set and get
>        scheduling policy/parameters
>
> SYNOPSIS
>        #include <sched.h>
> ```

Note that the functions are named with a leading **`sched_`**. That bit is important too. :)

Comment: thanks,I didn't know that I should of called the function with sched_